# How to concat two string variable inside a function-javascript?

Tags: javascript

Trying to call a js function like ng-click="sort_by('sourceCode'+':'+'sourceId')"  and concat the two variable with ':' .
Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

If `sourceCode` and `sourceId` are variables, then you should remove the quotes around them. You can also use the `concat()` method:

```
sourceCode.concat(':', sourceId);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat

Comment: `concat` takes multiple arguments if you like, so no need to use the inner `+`

Comment: Using angular js : I am calling the controller fn from ng-click like:                                          ng-click="sort_by('sourceCode')"           the param being the ng-model variable.                                                                                                                                               <tr data-ng-repeat="item in result">
                            <td>{{item.sourceCode}}:{{item.sourceId}}</td></tr>

Comment: You can either setup `sort_by()` to do the concatenation, or create another function and call that; passing in your two variables and concatenating them as needed before then calling `sort_by()`.

Answer (score 0):

Several methods include:

```
[sourceCode, ':', sourceId].join('');

sourceCode.concat(':', sourceId);

sourceCode + ':' + sourceId;
```

The first method (`Array.prototype.join`) is when you have a potentially large number of strings to concatenate together, it's helpful to be able to organize/format them in the confines of an array. Then you just join them.

The second method isn't very common.

The third method is just plain old string concatenation with the `+` operator.

Comment: added a 3rd method which concatenates first then calls the actual function

Answer (score -1):

**Updating in 2024**

I was searching for a way to achieve string concatenation in modern JavaScript. Here's a simple function that demonstrates how to concatenate two values into a single string:

```js
/**
 * Concatenates two values into a single string.
 *
 * @param {any} arg1 - The first value to be concatenated.
 * @param {any} arg2 - The second value to be concatenated.
 * @returns {string} The concatenated string.
 */

const arg1 = 'Hello';
const arg2 = 'World';

const concatStr = (arg1, arg2) => String(arg1) + String(arg2);

console.log(concatStr(arg1, arg2)); // Output: HelloWorld
```